# Try to find upgrade RAM for KVR667D2D8P5

Tags: memory

We have some really old servers in the lab from 2010s and we are trying to find compatible RAMs. The existing ones are KVR667D2D8P5/2G. Its specs say:

2GB 256M x 72-Bit DDR2-667
CL5 Registered w/Parity 240-Pin DIMM

I found some DDR2-667 PC2-5300F 4GB RAM sticks but they didn't match the slots in this machine. My question is, how I can find compatible 4GB RAM for this server? More specifically, does Crucial CT2KIT51264AA667 match？

Comment: http://www.crucial.com

Comment: What is wrong with KVR667D2D8P5/4G, for example? Similar but instead of 2G sticks, 4G sticks. Here: https://www.powersourceonline.com/buy-equipment/kingston_parts-new-KVR667D2D8P54G-cey-en.jsa

Comment: oh well, I found some KVR667D2D8P5/4G available, but they are pretty expensive, around $80~90 each. Just to see if I can find cheaper alternatives.